# Program don't create CSV file

Tags: python, csv

Non work functions `writerows()` and `open()`.

I have recycled image throw 2 loops **for** and give values *x,y,pix[x,y]*. Value *pix[x,y*] distributed to *r,g,b*. Array **header** have titles of table and array **result** have suits for table column *x,y,r,g,b.*

Code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75j6n.jpg)

```
import csv
import cv2
import os
from PIL import Image  # Подключим необходимые библиотеки.



image = Image.open("S45-3-4.jpg") #Открываем изображение.
width = image.size[1] #Определяем ширину.
height = image.size[1] #Определяем высоту.
pix = image.load() #Выгружаем значения пикселей.

for x in range(height):
   for y in range(width):
     r, g, b = pix[x, y]
     results = [x, y, r, g, b]
     headers = ['x', 'y', 'r', 'g', 'b']

     with open('seed45-3-4.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        write = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
        write.writerows(headers)
        write.writerows(results)
```

Console output information:

```
E:\LinesColor2\venv\Scripts\python.exe E:\LinesColor2\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\LinesColor2\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    write.writerows(results)
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not int

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as OpenCV related, when the only thing you do is import it, and never use it afterwards? Don't abuse tags, you're wasting people's time.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `writerow` method instead of `writerows` as you are attempting to write only a single line at a time in the csv file.

Also, you are creating a new file inside the for loop which is very slow and not what you are trying to achieve.

Here is what your code should look like:

```py
import csv
from PIL import Image  # Подключим необходимые библиотеки.

image = Image.open("S45-3-4.jpg") #Открываем изображение.
width = image.size[1] #Определяем ширину.
height = image.size[1] #Определяем высоту.
pix = image.load() #Выгружаем значения пикселей.e


with open('seed45-3-4.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
   headers = ['x', 'y', 'r', 'g', 'b']
   writer.writerow(headers)

   for x in range(height):
      for y in range(width):
         r, g, b = pix[x, y]
         results = [x, y, r, g, b]
         writer.writerow(results)
```

Comment: @toyota I have execut your recomendation. Error in 22 line stayed.